# Parse numbers in singe textbox for query

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’ve built a webform in Visual Web Developer Express 2008 to help me with my work.  I use a webform to run query requests that are emailed to me.  The inputs are in this format

12312 12312

12312 12312

12312 12312

12312 12312

I enter the first number in a textbox and the second number in another textbox and click a button that runs a query and returns the results in a gridview(single row).

```
string strConn, strSQL;
            strConn = AppConfig.Connection
strSQL = 'select fields from table where FirstNum=:FirstNum and      SecondNum=:SecondNum';

            using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection(strConn))
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strSQL, cn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":FirstNum", txtFirstNum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":SecondNum",
txtSecondNum.Text);
                cn.Open();

                using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dgResults.DataSource = rdr;
                    dgResults.DataBind();
                }
                cn.Close();
            }
```

I had an idea to help me speed up my work.  I’d like to be able to past both numbers in a single textbox

( like this 12312 12312 )

and have the code parse out the nubmers for the query. Or even better would be to past all of them in a multiline textbox like this

12312 12312

12312 12312

12312 12312

12312 12312

And have them all parsed and the query run for each line and the results all output to one gridview.  I’m just not sure how to approach this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
string[] lines = textBox.Text.Split( '\n' );
foreach( var line in lines )
{
    var values = line.Split( ' ' );
    var num1 = int.Parse( values[0] );
    var num2 = int.Parse( values[1] );
    // do what you need to with num1, num2
}
```

You're going to want to add more error handling logic and resiliency to the code above - especially if the input comes from a human being.

Comment: I've determined that there are 4 spaces between the numbers in each row in the email.  When I add 4 spaces to the second split I get an error 'too many characters in character literal' and if I leave it the array size is 6.......aha i can just change the second values from 1 to 5 like this values[5]....sorry I'm slow at this